# confusion about scope resolution operator in c++

Tags: c++, templates

what **::** does in   line  :    ***return ::operator new(size, ::std::nothrow);***
and why the class is using template when there is no use for template type T

```
template<typename T>
class DefaultMemoryAllocator
{
public:
  static inline void *Allocate(size_t size)
  {
    return ::operator new(size, ::std::nothrow);
  }
  static inline void Deallocate(void *pointer, size_t size)
  {
    ::operator delete(pointer);
  }
};
```

Comment: It's "scope resolution operator". And the reason for the type is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the *scope resolution operator* `::` like this means that the *global* `operator new` and `operator delete` functions are called, as opposed to ones that might have been overridden for that class.

You'll probably find that this function is part of a memory policy class, and is called from the class' `operator new` and `operator delete` overridden functions.

Comment: why the class is using template when there is no use for template type T?

Comment: @tohidprogram That might be easier to say if you shared where the class is used, and for what.

Comment: It looks to me like it's a snippet from a policy type framework based on the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP - Google that). *That* particular member function doesn't use the `T`, but other ones probably do.